# SQL Error 1292 trying to update row field

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling

I'm trying to update a field called "Syllabus" using this SQL query:

```
UPDATE `cursos` c
SET c.SYLLABUS = 'https://www.upv.es/pls/oalu/sic_asi.Busca_Asi?
P_VISTA=&P_IDIOMA=i?p_codi=' + c.CODE + '&p_caca=act'
WHERE c.SYLLABUS LIKE "" AND c.CENTER NOT LIKE "Study Abroad"
```

But I'm getting this weird error saying I'm trying to input a DOUBLE value on line 2 whenever I try to execute it. Any suggestions on how I could fix this problem?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You probably need to convert `code` to a string.

Comment: use apostrophes in `c.SYLLABUS LIKE '' AND c.CENTER NOT LIKE 'Study Abroad'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably the `+`.  This only does string concatenation in SQL Server and related databases.

This may do what you want:

```
UPDATE cursos c
    SET c.SYLLABUS = CONCAT('https://www.upv.es/pls/oalu/sic_asi.Busca_Asi?P_VISTA=&P_IDIOMA=i?p_codi=',
                            c.CODE, '&p_caca=act')
WHERE c.SYLLABUS = '' AND c.CENTER NOT LIKE 'Study Abroad';
```

Comment: I tried that and seems to work at first when I do the query simulation, but when I try to apply it I get the next error #1146 - Tabla 'carjimri_cursos.SYLLABUS' doesn't exist.